# NestJS + mongoose + mongoose-audit-trail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to use the 'mongoose-audit-trail' plugin in nestjs, but I'm getting the following error "Operation 'histories.findOne()' buffering timed out after 10000ms"

```
export const s = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Product);
s.plugin(require('mongoose-audit-trail').plugin);
```

Apparently there seems to be something in the connection that you couldn't use!

Or if anyone has any tips on another plugin for @nest to generate change histories I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I have recently been working on something similar. I had a problem where I couldn't get existing audit plugins working with nestjs and some of the stuff I have been working on.

I forked an existing library, and my plan is to merge it back and contribute to the original project. However, work has been crazy so not had a chance to finish it.

Maybe this can help you, if you take a look at my recent commits you'll see the modifications I have made.

https://github.com/piercy/mongoose-history-trace/tree/feat/saas

usage wise, you should just be able to use it as a plugin, passing in a few options.  From what I can tell, it does work, and does everything you might need for a nestjs, mongoose audit trail.... but it should be noted that while I am working on this, I haven't really tested or put it into a production environment yet.

You are welcome to use this or even finish it off if you want.  Sorry I couldn't just give you a plugin to use but hopefully this helps get you in the right direction.

Original Library is here: https://github.com/WelingtonMonteiro/mongoose-history-trace

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to db with `MongooseModule.forRoot()` or `MongooseModule.forRootAsync()` It's not the same as `mongoose.connect()`...

Your plugin tries to get connection from mongoose, but there is not opened one...

So I've Got Solution for this plugin: create `mongoose.connection` from module like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './services/app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { ConfigService } from './services/config/config.service';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [LargeFamilyModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {

        mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
        mongoose.connect(configService.db.uri)

        return configService.db
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
      
    },),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It's not a good idea to create to identical db connections, but for this issue it works.